# Polymer.dom(e).localTarget irregularity

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

While I was trying to get data binding up and running using fire(), I noticed that there's something weird going on with the Event object. Whenever I dump the entire (Polymer-wrapped) Event in the console, the `localTarget` entry is bound to the DOM element I'd expect and want. However, when I dump the `localTarget` directly, it is bound to the child element firing the event, i.e. the `rootTarget`. I've attached my code below, along with the console output it produces.

```
updateLatLonValues: function(e){
  console.log(Polymer.dom(e), Polymer.dom(e).localTarget)
}
```

produces the following output

[image: LocalTarget console output]

I'm stumped. Is this a bug, or am I missing something?